# How to generically implement methods from an abstract which uses generics?

Tags: java

The below gives me the compilation error: "Method does not override method from its superclass".

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> {
  protected abstract void doThing(T thing);
}

public abstract class BaseBaseClass<T> extends BaseClass {

  @Override
  protected void doThing(T thing) {
    System.out.println("hi");
  }
}
```

Comment: the error is correct, you have an `@Override` annotation on a class that does not extent anything, so how can it `Override` anything?

Comment: updated the post, it does actually extend the base class and gives the error

Comment: You extends uses raw types so the error message is still expected and  correct. `extends BaseClass` is not the same as `extends BaseClass<T>` the first is the same as `extends BaseClass<Object>`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your BaseBaseClass needs to extend BaseClass?

```
public abstract class BaseBaseClass<T> extends BaseClass<T> {
```

Of course, at that point, it doesn't look like it needs to be an abstract class anymore.

Comment: It is. As long as the `abstract` modifier is used. An abstract class does not necessarily has to have an abstract method. ;-)

Comment: it does extend the base class, just a typo in my psuedo code, I edited the post. The code in the post gives the same error.

Comment: Seems you still have a typo... compare yours to mine... extends is in the wrong place.